# Petersen Graphs on an nxm integer grid with restrictions on edge formation

Tags: graph-theory

Let $P$ be the Petersen graph. Prove or disprove that there is a unique pair of non-negative integers (x,y) on the integer grid $\mathbb{Z}/\langle4\rangle \times\ \mathbb{Z}/\langle4\rangle$ such that no edge in $P$ is "accidentally incident" to an extra vertice. The graph $P$ has an accidental incidence iff $\exists v \in P \ \text{such that} \ \deg(v) \not= 3  $ Does changing the grid to $\mathbb{Z}/\langle4\rangle \times\ \mathbb{Z}/\langle3\rangle$ change the truth value of the claim? $\mathbb{Z}/\langle3\rangle \times \mathbb{Z}/\langle3\rangle$?

For example on the integer grid $\mathbb{Z}/\langle5\rangle \times\ \mathbb{Z}/\langle4\rangle$:

[Petersen on $\mathbb{Z}/\langle5\rangle \times\ \mathbb{Z}/\langle4\rangle$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aKgW.png)

with points A(2, 2), B(0, 3), C(3, 2), D(1, 4), E(3, 3) F(2, 4), G(4, 4), H(4, 1), I(2, 0), J(0, 0)

However, an invalid assignment of vertices to the grid, or equivalently, a $P_0$ with an accidental incidence is as follows: (simply change A(2, 2) to A(0, 2))

[Petersen with an accidental incidence on $\mathbb{Z}/\langle5\rangle \times\ \mathbb{Z}/\langle4\rangle$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W4pb.png)

with points A(0, 2), B(0, 3), C(3, 2), D(1, 4), E(3, 3) F(2, 4), G(4, 4), H(4, 1), I(2, 0), J(0, 0)

What I really want to know:  Restrict your edges to only those created by straight lines: that is, polygons with one side who's total degree is 180˚. Is there a grid with a valid permutation (without "accidental incidence") that works?  If so, what is the smallest one?

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Comment: Did you leave something out? Was "there is a pair of non-negative integers $(x,y)$" supposed to be "there is pair of non-negative integers $(x,y)$ **SUCH THAT [SOMETHING]**"?

Comment: @PatrickStevens thank you!!

Comment: @bof I think you might be right.  I need to clarify what I am trying to ask (and this is why I am on here, attempting to refine my question forming ability as well as my question answering ability). In my mind, and this may not be clearly stated as you say, but if you were to say (1,2), then your graph would be edgeless.

Comment: @bof Yes, I think maybe I should say such that (x,y) is a unique pair of integers in the cross product. What do you think?

Comment: @bof How do I say that if all vertices were places on (1,2) then there would be no distance between them and hence no edges?  What sort of description do I need to assign to the edges?  They must have non-zero length?

Comment: @MorganRodgers maybe I am confusing permutation with isomorphism.  Will change now.  Take a look at the example for accidental incidence, and notice that deg(A) = 5.  How do I describe this, technically?